# TextWrangler - move text to the end of the line

Tags: sorting, text, grep, textwrangler

I have a text file containing only text lines like this:

```
(abc) defghjklmnop
```

I want the whole bracket to be at the end. So it should look like this:

```
defghjklmnop (abc)
```

The text in the bracket and the text after it vary from line to line.
How can I do this in TextWrangler?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Search for this:

`(\(.*\))(\s)(.*)`

and replace it with this (using back references to the groups in parentheses above):

`\3\2\1`

This will also preserve the whitespace between the two groups.